# Ubuntu 22.04 second monitor connected via display port not detected

Tags: drivers, 22.04, multiple-monitors, display

I connected a seconde monitor in the display-port but it's not detected by Ubuntu 22.04. which it was working with windows.
I have this output:

```
    sudo lshw -c video
       *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 530
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1024,768
       resources: irq:125 memory:e0000000-e0ffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

is there any solution for that ?